# Search function for books

Tags: c++, search

I was making a library program for trying to practice C++. I wanted to use a vector to store all the books, the books being a struct to hold the general things the books would have.

```
struct Book
{
    string  bookName; // book's name
    string  bookAuthor; // book's author
    string  bookID; // a random generated string
    int     bookType; // what type of book
};
```

The books in the library would be stored in a vector. To find one of these books I used a function that takes in a bookId parameter and uses it to find the book.

```
Book LibrarySystem::LocateBook(string bookId)
{
    /* May not be the fastest search algorithm */

    for (int i = 0; i <= mBooks.size(); i++)
    {
        Book result = mBooks[i];
        if (bookId == mBooks[i].bookID)
        {
            return result;
        } 

        else 
        { 
            cout << "FAILED TO FIND " + bookId << endl;
        }
    } 
}
```

This works but I was wondering if it could be faster. Looking at it, I am going through it one by one checking if the `bookId` is equal to the one provide in the parameter which seems slow.

I did do a small test to check if it all worked. I created a function:

```
string LibrarySystem::BookDataOutput(string bookId)
{
    Book book = LocateBook(bookId);
    string data = 
        "Book author: " + book.bookAuthor + "\n" +
        "Book name: " + book.bookName + "\n" +
        "Book type: " + to_string(book.bookType) + "\n" +
        "Book Id: " + book.bookID;
    return data;
}
```

Which outputs a single string with all the book's information. It uses `LocateBook` to find the the book with the `bookId`.

I run in main:

```
int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
    /* Seed the random generator */
    srand(time(NULL));

    LibrarySystem library;

    library.RegisterBook("Test1", "Test1", BOOK_TYPE::Adult, "test1");

    cout << library.BookDataOutput("test1") << endl;

    cin.get();
}
```

and the output is:

```
Book author: Test1
Book name: Test1
Book type: 5
Book Id: test1
```

Which matches all the information I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your search is only by 1 parameter, a `map<string,Book>` would work a lot better than a vector.

```
map<string,Book> mBooks;
string LibrarySystem::BookDataOutput(string bookId)
{
    Book book = mBooks[bookId];
    string data = 
        "Book author: " + book.bookAuthor + "\n" +
        "Book name: " + book.bookName + "\n" +
        "Book type: " + to_string(book.bookType) + "\n" +
        "Book Id: " + book.bookID;
    return data;
}
```